# Application Pool Occasionally Spiking Memory Consumption

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool

We have just launched a new `MVC5` web site.  The site uses `Entity Framework` for its data and also implements a couple of `WebApi` services for some simple `AngularJS` pages used on the web site.

The site has gone through development and testing without a problem, but now it is installed on an `IIS 8.5` production server we are seeing the following entries in the IIS (WAS) event logs:

Here is first error:

```
A worker process serving application pool 'xxx' has requested a recycle
because it reached its private bytes memory limit.
```

Around 90 seconds later we see this error:

```
A worker process '4880' serving application pool 'xxx' failed to stop
a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data
field contains the error number.
```

Which is immediately (the same time to the second) followed by a third error:

```
A process serving application pool 'xxx' exceeded time limits during
shut down. The process id was '4880'.
```

Finally, we see another Application Pool reccycle event:

```
A worker process serving application pool 'xxx' has requested a recycle
because it reached its private bytes memory limit.
```

We are currently seeing this problem approximately once per day and it does not seem to be related to site traffic/loading.

The reason we set the Application Pool to recycle on a *Private Bytes* consumption exceeded 4,194,304 KB (4 GB) - it normally (for perhaps 36 hours) sits at less than 1 GB, was because we had noticed that occasionally the Application Pools Private Memory consumption would increase linearly.  Again we did not see this during development or local testing.

We have tried running load tests of several hundred concurrent users across the application, but have been unable to replicate this error sequence.

We have also run the application locally for extended periods of time with ReSharper's *dotMemory* profiler and memory snapshots do not reveal any problems.

Are there any tools/techniques available that we can run on the production server that would give us more information on what is happening?